# If $ab+ba=1$ and $a^3=a$ in a ring, show that $a^2=1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I've been stuck on this exercise for a while now. It asks:

> If $ab+ba=1$ and $a^3=a$ in a ring, show that $a^2=1$.

I have a feeling this has to do with binomial expansion for rings, and the only mildly interesting equation I found was that $(a+b)^2 = a^2+b^2+1$, but that's all I've got. Can anyone provide me with a hint? I'd still like to challenge myself a bit. Thanks!

Comment: The first condition holds for all $b$ or for some particular $b$?

Comment: Multiply it by $a^2$ then play around with it?

Comment: [AoPS solution](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1813796p12093775).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have
$$a(ab+ba)=a\implies a^2b+aba=a$$
and
$$(ab+ba)a=a\implies aba+ba^2=a,$$
so that
$$a^2b=ba^2.$$
Multiplying both sides os last equation at the left by $a$, we get
$$ab=aba^2\implies ab(1-a^2)=0$$
Finally,
\begin{align*}
0&=(1-ba)(1-a^2)\\\
&=1-a^2-ba+ba^3\\\
&=1-a^2.
\end{align*}

Comment: Same as [this AoPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1813796p12093775) solution (= first match in [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24ab%2Bba%3D1%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24a%5E3%5C%20%3D%5C%20a%24&p=1)). Please cite it if that is the source.

Comment: It is not, I just solved it.

Comment: How does someone even figure this out?!?! I wouldn't have figured this out given 10 years.